# base64 Decode into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, base64

I'm trying to create a web panel for a client who parses information with base64 encoding. I have set up the way to decode it, and if I echo the decoded part in the loop ($data[1]), it will write the correct information. However, I need to be able to put the information into an SQL table and perform work on it before I do that. So, I'm trying to put the data into an array, but it is acting like the array is empty for some reason.

$postData has the base64 decoded information, and it was exploded using & as the exploding agent.

```
$tokens = array ();
for ($i = 0; count($postData) > $i; $i++) {
    $data = explode("=", $postData[$i]);
    $tokenAdd = array();
    $tokenAdd[] = $data[1];
    array_push($tokens, $tokenAdd);
}

var_dump($tokenAdd);
```

Comment: You should use `$tokens[][] = $data[1];` it does the same but with less function calls because you don't use `array_push()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you shure you are dumping correct variable? Because $tokenAdd is rewritten on each iteration.

```
$tokens = array ();
for ($i = 0; count($postData) > $i; $i++) {
    $data = explode("=", $postData[$i]);
    // token is empty array;
    $tokenAdd = array();
    $tokenAdd[] = $data[1];
    // push array with one string element into $tokens
    array_push($tokens, $tokenAdd);
}
// dump $tokens, not $tokenAdd
var_dump($tokens);
```

To simplify code you may try this

```
$tokens = array();
foreach ($postData as $postDataItem) {
    $data = explode("=", $postDataItem);
    $tokens[] = array($data[1]);
}
var_dump($tokens); // array(array('containing'), array('some'), array('strings'))
```

or even more simple, if you are ok dealing not with array of array and with array of strings

```
$tokens = array();
foreach ($postData as $postDataItem) {
    $data = explode("=", $postDataItem);
    $tokens[] = $data[1];
}
var_dump($tokens); // array('containing', 'some', 'strings')
```

Comment: Well I had code like the 3rd snippet, or exactly that I could have sworn, but it did not work. However, I think using the foreach made it work. Either way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
$count = count ( $postData );
$tokens = array ();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
    $data = explode ( "=", $postData [$i] );
    $tokens [$i] = $data [1];
}

var_dump ( $tokens );
```